# How to monitor a for-loop?

Tags: javascript, performance, for-loop

I would like to monitor the content of a for loop every X millisecond:

Here is an example, I expect to see progression percentage every 0.1 seconds :

```
for (i = 0, max = 9007199254740992, timer = setInterval(function() {console.log(100*i/max);}, 100); i < max; i++) {
  // something
}
clearInterval(timer);
```

But it does not output anything.

I would like not to add a test in my loop to avoid using useless computation time.

Comment: For loop will be completed within 100ms

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy – I has got nothing to do with entirely for loop but `initialization` in the `loop`

Comment: Callback function of `setInterval` will get invoked after the `duration`, as `clearInterval` is obviously invoked before `100ms`, `callback` is never invoked.

Comment: @Rayon What i meant to say is, before invoking the first function reference in the callBack queue, the for loop will be completed and the setInterval will also be cleared. So no O/P will be displayed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Due to the single-threaded nature of Javascript, your `setInterval()` callback can't possibly be called before the end of the `for` loop, no matter how long it takes to execute.

I'd recommend to do it the other way around: log elapsed time every N iterations.

```js
var res = [],
    ts = performance.now();

for(var i = 0, max = 1E6; i < max; i++) {
  if(!(i % 10000)) {
    res.push(performance.now() - ts);
  }
  // do something
}

console.log(res);
```

Or:

```js
var res = [],
    ts = performance.now();

for(var i = 0, iMax = 1E6; i < iMax; i += 10000) {
  for(var j = i, jMax = Math.min(i + 10000, iMax); j < jMax; j++) {
    // do something
  }
  res.push(performance.now() - ts);
}

console.log(res);
```

If you really want to log in real time, you'd have to yield control to the browser after each batch of N iterations. Performance wise, this will probably have a significant impact, though.

```js
var res = [],
    ts = performance.now();

function processBatch(i, iMax, sz) {
  for(var j = i, jMax = Math.min(i + sz, iMax); j < jMax; j++) {
    // do something
  }
  console.log((j * 100 / iMax) + '%', (performance.now() - ts).toFixed(2) + 'ms');

  if(j < iMax) {
    setTimeout(function() { processBatch(j, iMax, sz); }, 0);
  }
}

processBatch(0, 1E6, 10000);
```

**EDIT**: This third method was significantly updated. The previous version was erroneous.

Comment: You are correct about the reason it isn't called, but OP said they don't want to do a test in their loop " to avoid using useless computation time". Perhaps use nested loops with the test in the outer loop? Or web workers (seems overly complicated though)?

Comment: @samgak You're right. However, any measure will alter the results. I've added an alternate method, though.

Comment: you can get way cheaper than modulo by using a bit-mask: `mask = (1<<13)-1` `if(!(i&mask)){` does the same as %8192. downside: you have to stick with powers of 2. And your second attempt will overshoot, if `max%10000 !=0` better:  `for(var i=0, max=1E6;i<max;){ for(var cnt=10000; i<max && cnt--; ++i){ //....`

Comment: @Thomas You're right about the bitmask optimization, but I think the second method is better anyway. Regarding the 2nd issue, I've added a `jMax` variable to avoid computing the upper bound on each iteration (although the JS engine might actually figure out that i + 10000 is a constant in this block and optimize that by itself). Thanks!

Comment: @Arnauld `jMax = Math.min(iMax, i+10000)` or `for(/*... */; j < jMax && j < iMax; /*... */)`

Comment: @Thomas That should be done that way indeed in the more generic case where `iMax` is not congruent to 0, modulo 10000. Answer updated accordingly.